# hiding the keypad on iphone

Tags: iphone, hide, keypad

I have a form that looks like the following (see image). If the user hits the Login button, I want the keypad to disappear. How do I do that.

Note that TextFieldDelegate methods wouldnt get called since the user is simply hitting the UIButton (Login). Hence, anything I can put in the IBAction for this button?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally the keyboard should be dismissed automatically when the user taps somewhere outside of the textfield, but you can also manually hide it using

```
[textField resignFirstResponder]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 set delegate for your text field <UITextFieldDelegate>
 and over ride this method

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
   [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```